# Link to json method, "undefined method `stringify_keys'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hyperlink, format

I have a controller that I want to have 2 responses, the generic html and the json.  In my view, I want to have a link to said json.  I saw in the apidoc, someone said you accomplish designating the format in the link_to by doing somethin like this.

```
<h3><%= link_to "Indexes" , 
        params.merge({:format => "json"}) , 
       state_laws_path %></h3>
```

However, everytime I visit the page this link is located on ( state_laws/index.html.erb ) I get the following error.

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/state_laws":String

Extracted source (around line #3):
1: <h2>State Laws</h2>
2: <h3><%= link_to "Create State Law", new_state_law_path %></h3>
3: <h3><%= link_to "Indexes" , 
           params.merge({:format => "json"}) , 
           state_laws_path %>    </h3>
4: <ul id="state_laws">
5:   <% @state_laws.each do |law| %>
6:       <li class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can tell my view that I want a link that will go to the index action of the controller using the json format ?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Indexes", state_laws_path(params.merge(:format => "json")) %>
```

Passing the parameters to the `state_laws_path` method will make it return an URL that contains them. For instance, if your params contain `{:foo => "bar"}` and your state_laws_path is `"/state_laws"`, the above call would return the path `"/state_laws.json?foo=bar"`

Comment: Thanks. Someone needs to fix the comment or change the documentation found here, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to especially Hannu's response since it it no longer valid.

Comment: It is maybe a little confusing, but not incorrect. The syntax that I've mentioned is covered